# OPENCV bypass camera parameters refinement in stitching_detailed.cpp

Tags: opencv, camera, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm using the `stitching_detailed.cpp` for x-ray images on a flatbed. `stitching_detailed.cpp` estimates the camera parameters in two steps:

1. Crude estimation using `HomographyBasedEstimator`

   `HomographyBasedEstimator estimator;
   vector<CameraParams> cameras;
   estimator(features, pairwise_matches, cameras);`
2. Fine tuning the camera parameters using `Ray` or `Reproj` algorithms.

Sometimes it happened that the initial parameters estimated by the first step are good enough, however after passing the second stage, the camera parameters had 
`-1.#IND` values.

I tried to skip the camera parameter refinement step by removing the following line:

`(*adjuster)(features, pairwise_matches, cameras);`

As a result, the camera parameters stay good (no `-1.#IND`) anymore, but the stitching result is really bad. I picked up a case in which the program was able to stitch correctly with camera refinement step. I removed the 2nd step from the working solution and checked for the camera parameters. The camera parameters with and without camera refinement step stayed the same (minor changes in the rotation matrix and different focal lengths. `ppx` and `ppy` remained exactly the same). My questions are as follows:

1. Which steps can I remove from the stitching_detailed.cpp for my application. (illumination is the same, only translation and rotation involved).
2. Can I skip camera parameter refinement step. If so how?

I'm using opencv 2.4.9.